# Getting the lowest view on UIView using hitTest:?

Tags: iphone, ios, uiview

So my view look like this from lowest view

[L] UIView -> [K] view -> [M] view

[image: myview]

Since [K] is under [M] in some cases, when I do UIView hitTest: check on [L], it always returns [M] view.

Is there any way to get the lowest subview from hitTest: ?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I hope I understood your question:
You have the following view hierarchy and *View 1* is covered by *View 2*

```
+ Root View
| - View 1
| - View 2
```

Then you perform `-[UIView hitTest:withEvent:]` on the *Root View,* knowing the point lies inside *View 1* as well as inside *View 2.* But this method returns *View 2* because it is on the top.

If you want to get *View 1* instead you can use the following:

```
@implementation UIView (ExtendedHitTest)
- (UIView *)extendedHitTest:(CGPoint)point withEvent:(UIEvent *)event
{
    __block UIView *result;
    NSArray *hitTestSiblings = [self hitTest:point withEvent:event].superview.subviews;
    [hitTestSiblings enumerateObjectsUsingBlock:^(UIView *view, NSUInteger idx, BOOL *stop) {
        if ([view pointInside:[self convertPoint:point toView:view] withEvent:event]) {
            result = view;
            *stop = YES;
        }
    }];
    return result;
}
@end
```

With `anUIView.superview.subviews` you get all the siblings of `anUIView` with the topmost view as the last object—this means you'd first encounter *View 1* and then *View 2*

Answer (score 0):

You can traverse the superviews to find out the top one.

```
// Assume self is a UIView. If it's a UIViewController, replace self with self.view
UIView* v = [self hitTest:p withEvent:e];

if (v == self) {
    // The current view has been hit ...
}

while (v.superview != self) {
    v = v.superview;
}

// Now v is the view that you wanted
```